# HTML in IE6 floating clear problem

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

Can anybody explain to me why these three codefragments display exactly the same in **IE6**? (meaning that the 4th child DIV starts on the second 'line' while another one is 'cleared')

1:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div></div>
  <!-- below is cleared -->
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

2:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <!-- below is cleared -->
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

3:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <!-- below is cleared -->
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap { 
    position:relative;
    width:1000px;
    height:400px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:solid 1px black;
}

#wrap div { 
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:solid 1px black;
}

.clear { 
    clear:left;
}
```

Comment: This would be a lot easier to visually diff if you would use one or two CSS classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Use and abuse of TIDY HTML (there are online versions)

I ran against your div:

```
<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
  div.c3 {position:relative;width:1000px;height:400px;padding:0px;margin:0px;border:solid 1px black;}
  div.c2 {clear:left;float:left;width:150px;height:100px;background-color:blue;padding:0px;margin:0px;border:solid 1px black;}
  div.c1 {float:left;width:150px;height:100px;background-color:blue;padding:0px;margin:0px;border:solid 1px black;}
  /*]]>*/
  </style>
```

And code...

```
  <div class="c3">
    <div class="c1"></div><!-- below is cleared -->

    <div class="c2"></div>

    <div class="c1"></div>

    <div class="c1"></div>
  </div>
```

Much cleaner.
This site might answer your questions on the buggy IE6 implementation:

http://css-class.com/articles/explorer/floats/floatandcleartest1.htm